# Give an example of a continuous function on an open interval which is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Here is the full question:
Prove that every continuous function on a closed interval is Riemann integrable. Give an example of a continuous function on an open interval which is not integrable. 
I think he might be Riemann integrable for the second question because I'm pretty sure that every continuous function on an open interval is integrable just by definition. If that's not true, does anyone have any ideas for the answer?

Comment: It's not true. What about a function on $(0,1)$ that goes to infinity as $x \to 0$? Not every such function will work, but I bet you can think of one that does.

Comment: I really hope you start to develop an intuition for this type of question, because that will make you a mathematician. Fight as hard as you can to answer this kind of question for yourself. I really hope you come to see this as trivial, rather than hard work, or out of your range.

Comment: Just make precise what you mean by integrable; that's the whole key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with open intervals is that they are not compact, so infinities can crop up.

Let $I=(0,1)$, and let $f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$.

Then $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ does not exist, in fact it diverges to infinity.